# Changing Coordinate System of Census TIGER data in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, tiger

I have the block group files from the Census TIGER dataset, and am trying to line them up with some [GIS Data from HUD](http://egis.hud.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/ab2384beec924980b6a69fb60304a734_0).

When I load them both into ArcGIS, I see that the files do not quite align, when they should:

[image]

Using this site (http://prj2epsg.org/search), I discovered that the TIGER files use the [NAD83 GCS](http://prj2epsg.org/epsg/4269), while the HUD files use the [WGS 84 GCS](http://prj2epsg.org/epsg/4326).

Assuming the different coordinate systems was the cause of the misalignment, I attempted to use the [Project tool in ArcToolbox](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000007m000000) to project the TIGER files to the WGS 84. However, after doing so, and loading in the newly created layer, I end up with the exact same picture as above, even though both layers are now in WGS 84.

I'm a little lost on what to do now.

---

As requested, I am including screenshots showing the projection process.

[image: Selecting Projection Tool]

[image: Choosing WGS84]

[image: Final Step Before Projection]

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of the step(s) you took to change the coordinate system of your shapefile

Comment: @whyzar I just edited the post to include the screenshots. Let me know if there's any more information I can provide

Comment: Make sure that the data frame's coordinate system is WGS84 when comparing the reprojected data to the HUD data. What's the actual offset? I compared the HUD geodatabase (it actually uses EPSG::3857 AKA web Mercator) to an Esri topographic basemap and it lined up pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found the cause. For some reason I don't understand, the TIGER files from 2015 are slightly different from the TIGER files released in 2016.  I was comparing the 2016 TIGER files to the 2016 HUD files, but after some trial and error, I discovered that I had to use the 2015 TIGER files with the 2016 HUD files, and then everything lined up.